# Using WF to send message to Windows Server ServiceBus

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, workflow-foundation-4, azureservicebus

I'm trying to send messages to a local Topic created in Windows Server ServiceBus.
I started from examples by [Roman Kiss](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/276400/Using-Windows-Azure-Service-Bus-Messaging) and [Paolo salvatori](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh709041.aspx).

I'm stuck with the following exception:

```
Service namespace cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: serviceNamespace
```

This is the service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INotificationService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "*", IsOneWay = true)]
    void Process(string notification);
}
```

My config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 

       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />       

    </startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <!-- In this extension section we are introducing all known service bus extensions. User can remove the ones they don't need. -->
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="connectionStatusBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ConnectionStatusElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="serviceRegistrySettings" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ServiceRegistrySettingsElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="netMessagingTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="tcpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="httpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="httpsRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpsRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="onewayRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.RelayedOnewayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="basicHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.BasicHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="webHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WebHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="ws2007HttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WS2007HttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netTcpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netOnewayRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetOnewayRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netEventRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetEventRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netMessagingBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="sharedSecretCredentials">
        <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
          <tokenProvider>
            <sharedSecret
              issuerName="ServiceBusDefaultNamespace"
              issuerSecret="--PrimarySymmetricKey retrieved with Get-SBNamespace--" />
          </tokenProvider>
        </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <client>

      <endpoint name="TopicPublisher"
                address="sb://[machinename]/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/NotificationService"
                binding="netMessagingBinding"
                contract="INotificationService"
                behaviorConfiguration="sharedSecretCredentials" />
  </client>
  </system.serviceModel><appSettings>
    <!-- Service Bus specific app setings for messaging connections -->
    <!--<add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://[your namespace].servicebus.windows.net;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=[your secret]" />-->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is my ServiceBus.config file (required to avoid a "The Uri provided [machinename] does not match Service Bus domain: servicebus.windows.net." Exception, look [here](http://abhishekrlal.com/2011/03/22/clientsdkconfig/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- the root web configuration file --> 
<configuration> 
   <Microsoft.ServiceBus> 
     <relayHostName>[machinename]</relayHostName> 
     <stsHostName>[machinename]</stsHostName>    
    <acmHostName>[machinename]</acmHostName> 
   </Microsoft.ServiceBus> 
</configuration>
```

This is the very simple workflow:

[image: workflow to send a notification]

And finally this is the console:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activity publisher = new Publisher();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type ctrl+q to exit or enter to insert a notification");
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q && key.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the notification");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't understand!");
                    continue;
                }

                var notification = Console.ReadLine();
                var notificationMessage = new BrokeredMessage(notification);
                var inputs = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Notification", notificationMessage } };
                try
                {
                    WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(publisher, inputs);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I created the NotificationService Topic using [Service Bus Explorer 2.1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a).
The Azure SDK version is 2.1.4 installed via NuGet and I'm using Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1